# Can't find a solution to fix shake motion in xcode 7, swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I've been struggling with the problem quite  a lot and searched for the answer, but couldn't find any, hope I'll get some answers here. 
So, when I run my project in the simulator and if I choose from /Hardware -> Shake gesture/ , then the code will have a breakpoint in code.
Right on the first line that says if motion == .MotionShake ... It breakpoints. Does anyone have ideas?

```
override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
        fadeFortune()

        }
}
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
        newFortune()
        }
}
override func motionCancelled(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
        newFortune()
        }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, selecting the Shake gesture is injecting a breakpoint where you have not manually set one?

Sometimes you accidentally click the edge of the text editor by the line number and add a breakpoint without realizing it. This may be the case.  Look for the little blue breakpoint flag at that line in your code, and if it's there, drag it off to remove it.

Comment: Thank you!!! Indeed, I had added accidentally a breakpoint without realizing it and after removing it, code is working perfectly in the simulator.